# ParseException in Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running the below Hive query (MapR Version 0.12):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.AMT1, A.AMT2
FROM (
  SELECT ID as ID, NET_AMOUNT as AMT1
  FROM TEST_TABLE
  WHERE DATE_BY >='2012-10-01' AND DATE_BY <='2012-10-31') as q
  JOIN (
    SELECT ID as ID, NET_AMOUNT as AMT2
    FROM TEST_TABLE
    WHERE DATE_BY >='2013-10-01' AND DATE_BY <='2013-10-31') as r  
  ON q.ID=r.ID ) A
```

But I am getting this error:

> **Error :** FAILED: ParseException line 2:2 cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' 'ID' in subquery source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems some issue with your query, which I think should be like this:

```
SELECT q.ID,q.AMT1,q.AMT2 FROM  
(SELECT ID as ID, NET_AMOUNT as AMT1 FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE DATE_BY >='2012-10-01' AND DATE_BY <='2012-10-31')  q 
JOIN (SELECT ID as ID ,NET_AMOUNT as AMT2 FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE DATE_BY >='2013-10-01' AND DATE_BY <='2013-10-31')  r
on (q.ID=r.ID )
```

But as you are comparing DATES, and as @Antariksha ponited out you need to cast it.
But I prefer a better option, to compare the DATE in timestamp format. So in that case your query will look like this :

```
SELECT q.ID,q.AMT1,q.AMT2 FROM  
(SELECT ID as ID, NET_AMOUNT as AMT1 FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE unix_timestamp(DATE_BY,"<your date patern>") >=unix_timestamp('2012-10-01',"YYYY-MM-DD") AND unix_timestamp(DATE_BY,"<your date patern>") <=unix_timestamp('2012-10-31',"YYYY-MM-DD"))  q 
JOIN (SELECT ID as ID ,NET_AMOUNT as AMT2 FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE unix_timestamp(DATE_BY,"<your date patern>") >=unix_timestamp('2013-10-01',"YYYY-MM-DD") AND unix_timestamp(DATE_BY,"<your date patern>") <=unix_timestamp('2013-10-31',"YYYY-MM-DD"))  r
on (q.ID=r.ID )
```

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: why is timestamp better than date? the resolution is the same.

Comment: Well there are multiple reasons:
1.) Timestamp will work from Hive version 0.8 to latest. So your query will be generic enough.
2.) The current DATE data type has only YYYY-MM-DD format, but timestamp supports date till millisecond. So thats another advantage.

But for this particular problem, I think Date / Timestamp both will work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast the date to be compared as date using `cast('your date' as date)` since it is currently a string.

This may not solve your problem so edit your question after trying it.